# Why does Jquery AJAX adds some path to the relative path?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this the below code

```
$.ajax({
        url: "search/prefetch",
        success: function (data) {
            $(".result").html(data);
            alert("Load was performed.");
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
```

the request, however, is made to `http://<myhost>/<another-path>/search/prefetch`

This request is performed when the current page is `http://<myhost>/<another-path>/<some-other-paths>`

How can I make the request to `http://<myhost>/search/prefetch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just prefix your url with a `/`

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/search/prefetch",
    success: function (data) {
        $(".result").html(data);
        alert("Load was performed.");
    },
    dataType: "json"
});
```

What you are currently doing is telling the browser to take the current url path and append this path to the end of it. By prefixing it with a `/` you now are telling the browser to take the current url path and replace it with this new path.

Answer (score 1):

Relativity is the answer.

`search/prefetch` => `mysite.com/<current_uri>/search/prefetch`

`/search/prefetch` => `mysite.com/search/prefetch`